# How to add XAMPP MySQL Path in Ubuntu environment variable?

Tags: 22.04, kubuntu, kde, files, environment-variables

I'm a new Ubuntu (Kubuntu) user. I migrated from Windows. I want to add MySQL bin path to environment variable on Ubuntu (Kubuntu). How to do it? Please help me!

Comment: I would normally edit my user's `.bashrc` (or `.bash_aliases`) file to modify the `PATH` environment variable. Do no forget to `export` the modified `PATH` environment variable. So, adding a line like this to the end of the file should be enough: `export PATH="$PATH:/mysql-bin-path"`.

Comment: How to open .bashrc?